# How to prevent negative revenue values in SQL and redistribute them to following months?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have a revenue table in SQL with columns for date and revenue. I want to create a logic that prevents negative revenue values, so that any negative revenue value is set to 0 and the negative amount is subtracted from the revenue of following months until it is fully offset.

For example, if I have the following revenue data:

| Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-09-01 | 1200 |
| 2018-08-01 | 400 |
| 2018-07-01 | -1000 |
| 2018-06-01 | 800 |
| 2018-05-01 | 600 |
| 2018-04-01 | 200 |
| 2018-03-01 | -200 |
| 2018-02-01 | 400 |
| 2018-01-01 | 200 |

The expected output should be:

| Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-09-01 | 600 |
| 2018-08-01 | 0 |
| 2018-07-01 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 | 800 |
| 2018-05-01 | 600 |
| 2018-04-01 | 0 |
| 2018-03-01 | 0 |
| 2018-02-01 | 400 |
| 2018-01-01 | 200 |

Here is some code to get started

```
WITH revenue_table AS (
    SELECT '2018-09-01' AS date, 1200 AS revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-08-01' AS date, 400 AS revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-07-01' AS date, -1000 AS revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-06-01' AS date, 800 AS revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-05-01' AS date, 600 AS revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-04-01' AS date, 200 AS revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-03-01' AS date, -200 AS revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-02-01' AS date, 400 AS revenue UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-01' AS date, 200 AS revenue
)

select * from revenue_table
```

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Can anyone suggest a solution or provide some sample code that achieves this logic?

- tried to create a rolling sum on the negative values and substract the positive ones
- Recursion, but seem very slow and did not really work

Comment: Create a cycle; inside this cycle find a negative revenue; set this revenue to zero and add it to the revenue of the first record whose date is bigger than the date of the negative revenue; repeat the cycle until there is no negative revenue or there is no record whose date is bigger than the date of the negative revenue. Should be easier to implement it first in your application and then to rewrite it in a SQL stored procedure.

Comment: @IVOGELOV so best bet is a recursive sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow the question correctly, we do need recursion here, so that we can iteratively distribute negative amounts over the following rows.

`least` and `greatest` should be good enough for the arithmetic:

```
with recursive
    data as (
        select r.*, row_number() over(order by date) rn from revenue_table r
    ),
    rcte (date, old_revenue, rn, new_revenue, rest) as (
        select null::date, 0, 0::bigint, 0, 0
        union all
        select d.*, greatest(d.revenue + r.rest, 0), least(d.revenue + r.rest, 0)
        from rcte r
        inner join data d on d.rn = r.rn + 1
    )
select date, old_revenue, new_revenue 
from rcte 
where rn > 0 order by date desc
```

| date | old_revenue | new_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-09-01 | 1200 | 600 |
| 2018-08-01 | 400 | 0 |
| 2018-07-01 | -1000 | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 | 800 | 800 |
| 2018-05-01 | 600 | 600 |
| 2018-04-01 | 200 | 0 |
| 2018-03-01 | -200 | 0 |
| 2018-02-01 | 400 | 400 |
| 2018-01-01 | 200 | 200 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pc-BqWiq)

Comment: This query only returns the new revenue values - but it does not update them in the database. I believe that the OP needs a CRON-like process which will periodically update the values in the table in order to distribute the negative revenue. For me a WHILE loop inside a stored procedure would be more appropriate.

Comment: @IVOGELOV: I don’t see an indication in the OP that they want `UPDATE` rather than `SELECT` - although it’s quite easy to turn the latter into the former if needed. Beware as well, if we update existing values periodically then we won’t be able to keep track of the rest (the negative amount that remains to be spread over the future rows), which may lead to invalid results.